# How can I create a Pandas frame from data stored in multiple nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python program in which I sweep multiple parameters and at each point I calculate a few results.  I then want to export the results in the form of a CSV (or Excel) report that, on each row, contains the parameters and results.  For example, here I sweep two parameters `i` and `j` and calculated `res1` and `res2` as a function of `i` and `j`.  (This is completely silly MWE though!)

```
res1 = dict()
res2 = dict()

for i in range(5):
    res1[i] = dict()
    res2[i] = dict()
    for j in range(5):
        res1[i][j] = i+j
        res2[i][j] = i*j
```

And I would like to create a CSV with 25 rows and 4 columns where first two columns are `(i, j)` combinations for which `res1` and `res2` are calculated and second two columns are `res1` and `res2` respectively.  A naive way of exporting such a CSV is as follows:

```
#### Naive CSV writing
print(', '.join(['i', 'j', 'res1', 'res2']))

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print(', '.join([str(i), str(j), str(res1[i][j]), str(res2[i][j])]))
```

I was wondering if there is a way to create a `pandas` frame from the dictionaries so that then I can export the reports more easily?

I know that `pandas.DataFrame` constructor accepts a dictionary that maps column headers to column values.  So, for example the following is a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

# generate results as before 

d = dict([('i', list()),
          ('j', list()),
          ('res1', list()),
          ('res2', list())])

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        d['i'].append(i)
        d['j'].append(j)
        d['res1'].append(res1[i][j])
        d['res2'].append(res2[i][j])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False)
```

Yet, the above does not look so elegant (and I think is not efficient either).  Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: why to create so complex dictionary if you can create simple list with rows `[i, j, res1, res2]` and convert it to `DataFrame`. OR you can use `csv` modulel to do `writerow( [i, j, res1, res2] )`

Comment: The reason is that apart from exporting the results, I want to use the data inside the program as well. Obviously it is easier (and less error-prone) to write `res1[2][3]` to reference result 1 and point (2, 3) rather than finding the row of the list that starts with `[2, 3]` and then finding which column contains result 1.

Comment: I don't understant it. You can create list with rows `[i, j, res1[i][j], res2[i][j]]` instead of using dictionares in last code. And then you can use it to create DataFrame or write it directly in file using module `csv`

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood your answer first time.  Yes, indeed that's a possible (and less complicated) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could create normal list

```
data = []
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        data.append([i, j, res1[i][j], res2[i][j]])
```

And then convert to DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['i', 'j', 'res1', 'res2'])

print(df)
```

Or directly write it using `csv` module

```
import csv

fh = open("output.csv", 'w')
csvwriter = cvs.writer(fh)

csvwriter.writerow(['i', 'j', 'res1', 'res2'])

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        csvwriter.writerow([i, j, res1[i][j], res2[i][j]])

fh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
p = np.array(list(product(range(5), range(5))))

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'i': p[:,0], 'j':p[:,1]})

def res(row):
    row['res1'] = res1(row['i'], row['j'])
    row['res2'] = res2(row['i'], row['j'])

    return row

df = df.apply(res, axis=1)
```

Now you can write the dataframe directly into a csv